# How to prove that $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been working on the proof of $A\smallsetminus B = (A-B)$ U $(B-A)$, when A and B are sets. I have gotten that down, however, in that proof I use (A-B) = A intersection !B.  I figured that out by thinking about it, however I don't know how to prove it with sets.

Where should I begin for (A-B) = A intersection !B?

Comment: $A\cap A^C=\varnothing$, which implies $A\subseteq B$. Is there a typo in your title?

Comment: @user143918 Do you mean $A \!\setminus\! B = A \cap B^C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: How is $A\smallsetminus B$ defined? What about intersection? Complement?